# Disadvantages of quoting integers in a Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I am curious about the disadvantage of quoting integers in MYSQL queries

For example

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE col1='3';
```

VS

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE col1= 3;
```

If there is a performance cost, what is the size of it and why does it occur? Are there any other disavantages other that performance?

Thanks
Andrew

**Edit:** The reason for this question 
1. Because I want to learn the difference because I am curious
2. I am experimenting with a way of passing composite keys from my database around in my php code as psudo-Id-keys(PIK). These PIK's are the used to target the record. 
For example, given a primary key (AreaCode,Category,RecordDtm)

My PIK in the url would look like this:

```
index.php?action=hello&Id=20001,trvl,2010:10:10 17:10:45
```

And I would select this record like this:

```
$Id = $_POST['Id'];//equals 20001,trvl,2010:10:10 17:10:45
$sql = "SELECT AreaCode,Category,RecordDtm,OtherColumns.... FROM table WHERE (AreaCode,Category,RecordDtm) = ({$Id});
$mysqli->query($sql):
......and so on.
```

At this point the query won't work because of the datetime(which must be quoted) and it is open to sql injection because I haven't escaped those values. Given the fact that I won't always know how my PIK's are constructed I would write a function splits the Id PIK at the commas, cleans each part with real_escape_string and puts It back together with the values quoted. For Example:
    $Id = "'20001','trvl','2010:10:10 17:10:45'"
Of course, in this function that is breaking apart and cleaning the Id I could check if the value is a number or not. If it is a number, don't quote it. If it is anything but a string then quote it.

Comment: Why not just always do the right thing instead of worrying about the performance of having the query parser fix your mistakes?

Comment: Why not always stick to *something* instead of worrying about premature optimizations?

Comment: Because I want to learn a bit more about why we don't just always put quotes around all values in queries. I am experimenting with a way to pass around composite keys from the database as single psudo Id's in the php code.

Comment: @strager I will add a description to my question to explain my motivation

Comment: @strager: I don't see how proper data typing is premature optimization.

Comment: In SQL Server the problem arises when the data type of the constant has a higher precedence than that of the column. This means that the column needs to be converted to that of the constant. This is basically like wrapping the column usage in a function call. It renders the predicate unsargable and means a scan needs to be used tather than an index seek. Not sure if the same applies in MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

The performance cost is that whenever mysql needs to do a type conversion from whatever you give it to datatype of the column.  So with your query

> SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE col1='3';

If col1 is not a string type, MySQL needs to convert '3' to that type.  This type of query isn't really a big deal, as the performance overhead of that conversion *is* negligible.

However, when you try to do the same thing when, say, joining 2 table that have several million rows each.  If the columns in the `ON` clause are not the same datatype, then MySQL will have to convert several million rows *every single time* you run your query, and *that* is where the performance overhead comes in.

Comment: I don't quite understand that. Wouldn't it just convert the data type once for the entire query? Ie convert '3' to 3 at the beginning and then use it?

Comment: For your query, yes, the conversion would be made once.  However, when joining, in order to make a correct comparison, the columns being joined on need to be the same type, hence converting every row in the table.

Comment: interesting. I can see how that would really slow performance.thanks

Comment: I had an issue with a query taking several seconds under this exact circumstance. Removing the quotes around the "status" integer improved performance greatly:

BEFORE:
/* 0 rows affected, 1 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 1.217 sec. */
AFTER: 
/* 0 rows affected, 1 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.265 sec. */

Comment: I encountered a sizeable performance penalty of around ~50ms when using WHERE IN(...) with quoted integers. The target table contained 30,000 rows and used an INT for the column. The query executes instantaneously when the correct data type is used in the IN element.

Comment: What about security against sql injection?

Answer (score 3):

Strings also have a different sort order from numbers.

Compare:

```
SELECT 312 < 41
```

(yields 0, because 312 *numerically* comes after 41)

to:

```
SELECT '312' < '41'
```

(yields 1, because '312' *lexicographically* comes before '41')

Depending on the way your query is built using quotes might give wrong results or none at all.

Numbers should be used as such, so never use quotes unless you have a special reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, I think there is no performance/size cost in the case you have mentioned. Even if there is, then it is very much negligible and wont affect your application as such.

Comment: Yes but of course this is a simplified example. I don't have a single query which is that simple. I think that @Chris Henry explains the fact well, that in a more complex query it would cause a performance issue.

Comment: @Andrew - @Chris explains the performance overhead in combination with Joins which is correct. But in case its only the implicit type conversion for eqaulity check in where clause, it is still negligible. Check @David's answer too which gives experimental values.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the wrong impression about the data type for the column.  As an outsider, I assume the column in question is CHAR/VARCHAR & choose operations accordingly.

Otherwise MySQL, like most other databases, will implicitly convert the value to whatever the column data type is.  There's no performance issue with this that I'm aware of but there's a risk that supplying a value that requires explicit conversion (using [CAST or CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)) will trigger an error.

Comment: In my practice I've had cases when mysql unexpectedly casted not the constant value (quoted integer), but the field itself. Thus index was not used.

Comment: @andrew: Figured I was clear that they are what you use to explicitly change data types, but I added a link to the documentation just in case.