# simple SQL statement takes longer time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disadvantages of quoting integers in a Mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918512/disadvantages-of-quoting-integers-in-a-mysql-query)

I have a very simple table Called Device on MYSql database.

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
| Field                             | Type         | Null | Key | Extra          |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
| DTYPE                             | varchar(31)  | NO   |     |                |
| id                                | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | auto_increment |
| dateCreated                       | datetime     | NO   |     |                |
| dateModified                      | datetime     | NO   |     |                |
| phoneNumber                       | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL |                |
| version                           | bigint(20)   | NO   |     |                |
| oldPhoneNumber                    | varchar(255) | YES  |     |                |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
```

This table has more than 100K records. I am running a very simple query

```
select * from AttDevice where phoneNumber = 5107357058;
```

This query takes almost 4-6 second, But when I change this query a little bit as shown below.

```
select * from AttDevice where phoneNumber = '5107357058';
```

It takes almost no time to get executed. 
Notice that phoneNumber column is varchar. I don't understand why the former case takes longer time and later doesn't. The difference between these two queries is the single quote. 
Does MYSQL treats these to query differently if so then why?

## EDIT 1

I used `EXPLAIN` and got the following output but don't know how to interpret these two results.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select * from AttDevice where phoneNumber = 5107357058;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Device    | ALL  | phoneNumber,idx_Device_phoneNumber | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6482116 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN select * from AttDevice where phoneNumber = '5107357058';
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                         | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |   Device  | ref  | phoneNumber,idx_Device_phoneNumber    | phoneNumber | 258     | const |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone explain me about the key, key_len and rows present in EXPLAIN query output?

Comment: have you tried to `EXPLAIN` the queries? That should answer your question.

Comment: Is it possible that the second time it's executing faster because it cached parts of the results in memory?

Comment: Q: Did you try "explain"?  What did it say w.r.t. to possible_keys, key, key_len, etc? Please post the two "explains".  Q: Why the "sql-server" tag?

Comment: In my humble opinion, when the value given for comparison with `phoneNumber` is in another datatype (unsigned integer in your example) the value is first cast to `VARCHAR`, which is probably the reason why it takes that extra time.

Comment: if this is mysql, why have you tagged as sql-server?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: I'm curious what the plan is for `where phoneNumber = UPPER('5107357058');`. If that does not use the index, then I would guess applying a function to the criteria affects index selection. And when using a numeric, an implicit function is being used. This would make sense because you don't know the value returned from the function. For example, should an index be used for: `where phoneNumber = '5%'`? Probably not if more than 10% of the phone numbers start with a `5`. Usage of the index is also dependent on the criteria (hence histograms to try to help selection, sometimes late parsing, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Thank you for the "EXPLAIN".  We all (including you, I'm sure) *knew* that the problem was that mysql had to convert the integer to a string, and had to do it for each row.  But your "EXPLAIN" proved it.

2) Here's a nice, short article about EXPLAIN:

> - http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/explaining-mysqls-explain
>
> The *possible_keys* shows which indexes apply to this query and the *key*
>   tells us which of those was actually used -... Finally the *rows* entry tell
>   us how many rows MySQL had to look at to find the result set.

```
Search value:   key:        type:  ref:   rows:  
-------------   ---         ----   ----   ----
5107357058      NULL        ALL    NULL   6482116
'5107357058'    phoneNumber ref    const  2
```

3) The "ref" column is the "The columns compared to the index".  In the second case, the string literal ("constant") '5107357058' was compared to the key "phoneNumber".  In the first case, there *was* no usable key (because your search condition was a completely different type); hence "ref" was NULL.

4) The "type" column is "The join type".  "Ref" means "All rows with matching index values are read from this table" (in this case, 2 rows).  "ALL" mans "full table scan". Which in this case means 6 million rows.

5) Here's the mysql documentation for "EXPLAIN":

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Answer (score 2):

You fooled MySQL into making a bad choice by NOT quoting the phone number.  Consider:

1. The column definition is varchar
2. In the first (unquoted) case you provided the value as an integer (long).  I would have thought MySQL could figure this one out, but obviously it didn't, and did a full table scan.
3. In the second (quoted) case, you gave the search key in the correct datatype (character) and MySQL chose the index over the full-table-scan.

Answer (score 2):

The varchar index cannot be used when you use a number as the operand, excerpt from the fine documentation on [implicit type conversions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the lookup in the following statement:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE str_col=1;
>
> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that MySQL has to convert the number into a varchar in the first example.  In the second example it does not.  I'm guessing that's where the difference is coming from.

Comment: Ya even I am suspecting so. I noticed one more thing here that for the first query the number of rows in `Explain` output has 6482116 rows whereas for the second query it has only 2 rows.

Comment: It's not using the key in the first one.  That's probably because you are not using the single quotes around the varchar criteria.  If you do it, it will use the key properly and run much faster.

Comment: 4-6 seconds difference from converting an integer value to a varchar value?

Comment: It's because it's not using the key (index).  It must be because the criteria is not in the correct type.

Comment: In the second case it's using the phonenumber key.  In the first it is not using any.

Answer (score 1):

The first example looks through the table one by one, the other one uses the index.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html
    If Key is MUL, multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column. The column is the first column of a nonunique index or a unique-valued index that can contain NULL values.

So instead of scanning all the null values, the second query look exclusively for for non-null values which speeds things up.

....I think.