# PDO::PARAM_INT is important in bindParam?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Add `PDO::PARAM_INT` or `PDO::PARAM_STR` have any meaning in Mysql query?

```
$sql  = 'SELECT TagId FROM tagthread WHERE ThreadId = :ThreadId';

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ThreadId', $threadid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Probably not. MySQL will automatically coerce a string to an int when necessary.

Comment: Well, don't you think that one meaning could be the documentation purposes it does?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, use it.

I did a few tests (with PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES `false`) and I found out that the quotes around the values will be different.

When you bind an integer value with `PARAM_INT` there will be no quotes in the query (A string value with PARAM_INT has quotes). If you bind an integer value with `PDO::PARAM_STR` there will be quotes and mysql has to cast to integer.

Examples:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':ThreadId', $threadid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$threadid = 123;
// SELECT TagId FROM tagthread WHERE ThreadId = 123
$threadid = '123test';
// SELECT TagId FROM tagthread WHERE ThreadId = '123test'
// mysql will cast 123test to 123
```

EDIT:

I further tested and read on that topic. Conclusion: `Implicit casting is dangerous and can lead to unexpected results.` Read more on that [here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/implicit-casting-you-dont-want-to-see-around). Another disadvantage to always use `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the performance. Read more on performance [Disadvantages of quoting integers in a Mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918512/disadvantages-of-quoting-integers-in-a-mysql-query)

So if your column is of type `[TINY|SMALL|MEDIUM|BIG]INT` than use `PARAM_INT`. And in case it is a `LIMIT` clause than cast to integer if the variable type in PHP is not integer.

Comment: Be careful with BIGINT data type though! See this StackOverflow case in which setting `PARAM_INT`(instead of leaving the default `PARAM_STRING`) resulted in incorrect value being passed to MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155966/bigint-truncated-via-pdo

Answer (score 1):

It depends! *See Your Common Sense*'s comment below.

If the value is a integer it should be treated as an integer.
Apply this with as many datatypes as possible.

If you don't set the Attribute of PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false, you will get a nasty error.

Solid example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE raw_field = :field LIMIT 1 OFFSET :offset;");
$stmt->bindParam(':field',  $field);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset);

if ($map_stmt->execute())
{
    $data = stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else
{
    echo 'Error :';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($map_stmt->errorInfo());
    print_r($map_stmt->debugDumpParams());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Will return back a nasty error containing:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ''0'' at line 1
>
> Query: SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE raw_field = 'home' LIMIT 1 OFFSET '0'

Useless you treat it as an integer, and it will remove the string (e.g.: ' ').

```
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**In a nutshell:**

You choose! Strict data or not..

Comment: Simple `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` will make your "nasty error" disappear in a puff of smoke.

Answer (score -3):

I cannot tell for all the drivers supported by PDO, but for MySQL it's OK not to use `PDO::PARAM_INT` most of time.

Therefore, it makes no sense to bloat your code with numerous `bindParam` calls. As a rule, just send your variables directly into `execute()`:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT TagId FROM tagthread WHERE ThreadId = ?';
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$threadid]);
```

Here your `$threadid` variable will be silently bound as a string, but it will make not a single problem for MySQL to compare it with integer value stored in database. *In reality*, everyone does it this way and never has any problem.

The problem with string type binding in `LIMIT` clause can be easily solved by switching the emulation mode OFF.

Note that `PDO::PARAM_INT` [doesn't cast your value](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit). This means if you're trying to bind a string type value using this mode, **it will be bound as a string** nevertheless, even if you explicitly set type to `PDO::PARAM_INT`. This mode will be actually applied only for integer values.

There are few edge cases where you may want to bind an integer explicitly though:

- peculiar column types, like `BIGINT`, or `BOOLEAN` that require an operand of exact type to be bound (note that in order to bind a BIGINT value with `PDO::PARAM_INT` you need a mysqlnd-based installation).
- some DBAs claim that complex queries with non-trivial query plan can be affected by a wrong operand type. Though no one has provided a verifiable example yet

All other issues are common for the loose typing and neither MySQL nor PDO binding has any special effect in them.

Also, to avoid possible problems **you should choose the right column types for your data.** Say, for big integers you should use `BIGINT`, while for any price-like data it has to be `DECIMAL`. And there will be not a single issue with comparison.

Comment: It's totally wrong and dangerous to always use `PDO::PARAM_STR`. You can get unexpected results. Example: `SELECT '3.0' = 3` vs. `SELECT '3.0' = '3'`

Comment: There are more examples [here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/implicit-casting-you-dont-want-to-see-around)

Comment: These examples are all right. If you store a decimal as a string, this would be expected behavior

Comment: And `SELECT 123456789012345678 = '123456789012345677'`? It will be compared as floating point.

Comment: Read the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html). `In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.`. By the way I have a 64-bit system and `SELECT 123456789012345678 = '123456789012345677'` is `1` for me.

Comment: You are comparing a *float* here. But the question was about integers, not floating point numbers. Go figure.

Comment: Good disclaimer *"I cannot tell for all the drivers supported by PDO"* because this won't work when using ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server. This attempt will result in the error: `SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification. Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int`. I love MySQL and this bypass is very nice - much cleaner syntax, but when I swapped out for MSSQL, everything is broken. Oh well, back to ugly explicit syntax for better interchangeability.