# bigint truncated via PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, biginteger

I came across a problem with storing a large integer in a `BIGINT` column on MySQL via PDO

If i run this test:

```
$number = "30123456789";
var_dump($number); //prints string(11) "30123456789"

$new_number = (int)$number;
var_dump($new_number); //prints int(30123456789)
```

So far so good...

If I run this SQL directly in MySQL:

```
update my_table set bigint_field = 30123456789 where id_field = 1
```

Everything works fine...

The problem arise when I try to save that number via PDO and I reduced the problem to this line of code:

```
//parameterized query
//update my_table set bigint_field = :bigint_field where id_field = :id_field
$statement->bindValue(":bigint_field", $new_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If the optional third `type` parameter is absent or equals `PDO::PARAM_STR` then the value is saved jut fine, if not the value is truncated to 58685709. If I try to save 20288976024, the value is truncated to 0. What is happening here

I'm running PHP 5.5.33 and MySQL 5.6.25 on Debian Wheezy x64

Comment: Just one thing came to my mind. Is your pdo mysqlnd-based?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not sure, how can I know that?

Comment: phpinfo(), pdo section, there should be the word "mysqlnd". Also it would be interesting to compare the results when emulation mode is on and off

Comment: Under PDO: PDO drivers > mysql. Under pdo_mysql: Client API version > 5.6.25

Comment: Then I'd suggest to install php-mysqlnd or whatever it called for Debian and try again. To see the complete reproduceable code snipped still would be very nice.

Comment: That did the job!! Thank you very much. Post it as an answer if you like and will mark it as accepted

Comment: Well, I am not after accepted answers at all but you gave me something much more valuable - a piece of knowledge, so I'll be able to help other people with the same problem. Going to update my PDO tutorial )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your case.

On a x86 system intval() already makes 2147483647
On a 64 bit system everything works fine.

Binding bigint values as strings may lead to wrong results, as value will be cast to a float and lose precision.

Edit: it turned out to be an old libmysql issue. Having PHP configured this way I was able to reproduce the problem:

```
$number     = 30123456789;
$new_number = 20288976024;
var_dump($number, $new_number);

$pdo->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bint_test(i BIGINT unsigned)");

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into bint_test values (?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindValue(1, $new_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM bint_test")->fetchAll());
```

prints out

```
int(30123456789)
int(20288976024)
[{"i":"58685717"},{"i":"0"}
```

Two possible solutions:

1. (Preferred) Install `php-mysqlnd`, which you have to do anyway, because mysqlnd is an new replacement for the old libmysql connector.
2. Turn emulation mode ON - a query that is constructed by PDO is also works flawless.

Comment: On a windows 7 x64 the only way I could make everything work fine was with php7 x64 and an apache 2.4 x64, both compiled with vc14....but on debian server it seems far more complicated to make it work

Comment: On Debian, PHP and MySQL are working fine apparently, the issue is somewhere in PDO

Comment: You should post the complete reproduceable code, from table creation to displaying results - so everione would be able to test.

Comment: Do you have any reference/citation for the *cast to float* statement? Although i do not use explicit type specifications but just out of curiosity I tried to verify your statement but no rounding occurred at all. This big int *2884545454545976024* saved without any issues as `PARAM_STR`

Comment: Thanks! What pdo parameter type should be used for a Bigint then? I mean by the people who want to explicitly specify it.

Comment: @HankyPanky PARAM_INT should work, at least for a 64-bit system. I wish I was able to reproduce the case from the OP but no success yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `php-mysqlnd` solution is not possible in HHVM: see https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3679