# What does ":" mean when using bindValue() in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

What does `:` mean before `id` in the example below? Is it necessary?

```
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Can I say `:id` is a variable?

If `PDO::PARAM_INT` is not necessary, why would I need to use it?

Comment: Placeholders are explained in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

`:id` is a named placeholder for the prepared query. Somewhere else in your code there's a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT stuff FROM something WHERE id = :id
```

that gets run through PDO's [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) function.

> If `PDO::PARAM_INT` is not necessary, why would I need to use it?

Safety / data consistency. See [PDO::PARAM_INT is important in bindParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751360/pdoparam-int-is-important-in-bindparam)

Answer (score 1):

> What does : mean before id in the example below? Is it necessary?

Nothing particular. It's just a syntax. Like a $ sign in front of a php variable. It is necessary in the query, to let the parser to distinguish a placeholder from any other query part. And so it makes sense to use exactly the same name in bindValue()

> Can I say :id is a variable?

Pretty much yes. By the meaming it is a variable, but to make it not confused with php variables it is called "a placeholder".

> If PDO::PARAM_INT is not necessary, why would I need to use it?

It has absolutely nothing to do with security. You may want to use this modifier only to tell a database that you are sending an integer. Speaking for mysql, this database is quite tolerant to the data types, and almost anywhere you may omit the type modifier - in this case the data will be bound as string. You may want to set it explicitly quite seldom: only if you are using a placeholder in LIMIT clause or when sending a bigint value involved in a math.

Comment: Can you please tell us kind sir if you pass a string in a variable that is declared to accept only integer values with PDO::PARAM_INT what will happen? In case an error is raised you can call that a bit of more "secure" way of doing things right? But then again you will have an answer on that to. How you will prove yourself? BTW i really like your profile image in here? It reminds me someone. ;) In case you down-voted me (yes i know how much you love me and my answers) thank you it means so much coming from YOU.

Answer (score 0):

> What does `:` mean before **id** in the example below? Is it necessary?

```
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Yes it is necessary. In [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) is defined that `:id` is a named-placeholder of your parameter-identifier. If you were using question mark placeholders, your parameter-identifier would be `1`.

The form of your named placeholder has to be like `:id`. If your named placeholder does not have that form then this leads to error.

- **Fatal error:**...for the right syntax to use near  `WHERE id = ::id`

> Can I say :id is a variable?

No, `:id` is your `parameter-identifier`

> If PDO::PARAM_INT is not necessary, why would I need to use it?

Declaring the expected data type is a good safety tactic (not that you can rely on this only for safety of course). In case you use [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) you can define the length of the data type to add more safety.